# When does MtGox lock accounts?

Tags: mtgox

When you sign up at MtGox, they say: please fill out the following to avoid your account getting locked.  They're referring to the member verification process (using govt ID and utility bill).

But under what circumstances will they lock my account if I cannot provide verification docs at the moment?  And what does "locked" prevent me from doing?  Does it prevent me from, for example, transferring BTC to another exchange or wallet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a provider that is no longer in business.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got mine locked because my YubiKey broke.

When you want to disable the YubiKey for your account, your account will be frozen *for two weeks*. I had my account information verified and still got locked.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "locked" is more exactly "AML flag", concerning money laundering regulations.

More or less everything that is "suspicious" can get you AML flagged.

A few publicly well known examples that will get you flagged are if you are accessing mtgox from the TOR network or other anonymous proxies; also if you are accessing many mtgox accounts from the same IP address.
 Many other reasons could get you flagged, most of them are not publicly known.

Being AML flagged will lock any withdrawal attempt, even for BTC withdrawals.

You will still be able to deposit and trade, but you wont be able to withdraw, until you verify your account with ID doc and utility bill.

Comment: Citation needed.

Comment: feel free to cite myself or magicaltux from the official mtgox irc channel ;) see also https://support.mtgox.com/entries/21651045-AML-Account-Statuses

Comment: That page makes no mention of "locked" accounts.

Comment: there are no "locked" accounts, there are limited accounts because they have been AML flagged for any suspicious activity and will need to verify to remove the withdrawal limits, that is respecting AML laws : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_Laundering_Control_Act http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_Money_Laundering